# I don t understand how value of variable is changing or initializing:

Tags: c#

I don't understand what is new value of variable. I don't get it how it works..
I cant find the answer nowhere..

i run it and x = 10  , n = 2 and y = 0? but i don t see the logic behind it.

```
int x = 5, y = 3, n;
x *= (2 & 2);
n = 2 | 2;
y *=(5 & 8); //  y = 0 ??
Console.WriteLine(x); // 10
Console.WriteLine(y); // 0
Console.WriteLine(n); // 2
```

x = 10 , but y = 0 ? I just don t get the logic...
I don't remember this form class but all of the sudden there it is.
How it works?

Comment: 5 and 8 have no bits in common. Therefore 5 & 8 == 0. Doesn't your textbook cover C# operators? Were there no online resources? An important thing to learn about programming is that you can't understand the meaning of an identifier by looking at it harder and longer. There is absolutely nothing intrinsic about the character `&` that is going to hint at what the C# compiler chooses to do when you throw `&` at it. That's purely arbitrary. But you can always look it up. You're right: You can't find the answer *nowhere*. Looking *nowhere* doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 is like 0101(2) which means 5 contains 4 (0100) and 1(0001)

8 is like 1000(2) which means 8 only contains 8 (1000)

& and | operator checks if values contains same elements which is true at same points or not.

so 5|8 will be contains 8 4 1 => 1101 and it converts to decimal like 13.

and 5&8 will be zero because 5 doesn't contains 8 and 8 also doesn't contains 4 and 1.

I'd like to introduce this webpage to learn about bitwise operators.

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301

Comment: You may need to explain that 0101 is a pattern of off and on bits. And lining up 0101 above 1000 makes the & and | operations very clear.